# Any workaround to getting a list to numpy array for keras input data?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, keras

I'm trying to train a CNN model on keras, my data looks like this

```
type(datain)
<class 'list'>
len(datain)
35000
type(datain[0])
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
datain[0].shape
(256,256,1)
```

And being my input data a list of arrays I get this error when trying to train the network

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

but when trying to do something like `np.array(datain)` as suggested here https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4823 my computer freezes/crashes. defining my input using python list takes like 60 seconds in total, but if I try as numpy arrays from the beginning but takes like 1 sec per `(256,256,1)` array, and is way too much time if I intent of doing various test and modifications to my network,
is there any work around for this problem?
 any way to use lists for keras?
a different way to define a numpy array?
or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: This may be too much for your computer's memory. Work with a generator.

Comment: what do you mean by generator?

Comment: Just to be sure, try first a small amount of data, like `np_data = np.array(datain[:100])` and see if the error still occurs.

Comment: [Generators explained](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

Comment: okay with 100, my computer didnt freeze and my network started to train

Comment: any example of this kind of generators for keras? I mean I got what you mean, or so I like to think, but keras wants batches of data, how to feed it properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a generator from your data.

A `generator` is a python concept, it loops and yields results. For Keras, your generator should yield batches of `X_train` and `y_train` indefinitely.

So, a simple generator that you can make is:

```
def generator(batch_size,from_list_x,from_list_y):

    assert len(from_list_x) == len(from_list_y)
    total_size = len(from_list_x)

    while True #keras generators should be infinite

        for i in range(0,total_size,batch_size):
            yield np.array(from_list_x[i:i+batch_size]), np.array(from_list_y[i:i+batch_size])
```

Use the generator in training:

```
model.fit_generator(generator(size,datain,dataout),
                    steps_per_epoch=len(datain)//size, 
                    epochs=...,...)
```