# Any better approach to solve MemoryError?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, out-of-memory, keras

I am working on deep learning. I am using Keras with tensorflow backend, and I have 36980 images to train. I want to use VGG16, so I resized all of them to (224*224) size. So the size of the train array is around 22GB (36980*224*224*3*4 bytes). When I try to load this amount data into a numpy array, python shows MemoryError.

I have thought of splitting the training set into 10 pieces and train my model on only one of such piece at a time. Is there any better approach to solve this problem? I am using Python 3 (64 bit version).

N.B.

- To get a good accuracy, I need as large image as possible, so I can't resize them to a smaller size. Moreover, it's necessary to use RGB images here.
- No `fit_generator()` solution please. A model trained using `fit_generator()` behaves abnormally while predicting, at least as far as I have seen.

Comment: Splitting the data is the way to go. Just make it efficient (load the next chunk in a second thread while processing the data already in the memory) and you can scale up as much as you want.

Comment: See the other current Keras question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47979861/any-workaround-to-getting-a-list-to-numpy-array-for-keras-input-data

Comment: "A model trained using fit_generator() behaves abnormally while predicting"... how is that?

Comment: @DanielMöller model.predict() from model.fit() and model.fit_generator() doesn;t match at all.

Comment: You very probably had a problem in the generator.

Comment: @DanielMöller I used the code of the Keras documentation. I used the flow_from_directory() generator.